# how to access the defined relation in blade view laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, laravel-blade

i want to access the defined relation in my blade view and show it i am doing like this in my invoice model

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasone('App\Client','id','client_id');
}
```

and here in invoice controller

```
 public function show(Invoice $invoice)
{
    $clients = Invoice::with('users')->get();
    return view('admin.invoices.show', compact('invoice', $invoice),compact('clients',$clients));
}
```

and finally in my view i did this

```
<td>{{ $clients->users->first()->title }}</td>
```

but when i try to view i get this error

```
Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance
```

when i dd the $clients i get results in relation like below

```
 #relations: array:1 [▼
    "users" => Client {#309 ▼
      #fillable: array:14 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:17 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "title" => "شسی"
```

Comment: `hasone` has typo, correct is `hasOne`

Comment: Function names are __caseinsensitive__

Comment: that was the Auto complitation i corrected that but no that was not the problem still get the same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`get()` always returns a `Collection`, with 0...N results. With this line:

```
$clients = Invoice::with('users')->get();
```

`$clients` will be a `Collection` of `Invoice` objects. The `users` property doesn't exist on the `Collection`, it exists on each `Invoice` inside the `Collection`.

Make sure you're looping through your `$clients` collection and accessing `users` on the individual `Invoice` items.

---

NB: While not your primary issue here, @Joshua's note about the `users` is correct. The `hasOne` relationship will return either a Model instance if the relationship exists or `null` if the relationship doesn't exist. I would also suggest changing the name from `users` to `user`, and maybe adding some protection for when the relationship doesn't exist:

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
    ...
        <td>{{ $client->user->title ?? 'No Title' }}</td>
    ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: complete and clear :) thanks you saved me a lot of time and i learned from that , that was the part i was trying to understand between the collection of models and a signle model thanks thanks :)

Comment: just 1 more question is that can i get the relation without the get() method ???$clients = Invoice::with('users');   like this is it correct to do ?

Comment: @Farshad I'm not sure what you're trying to do (the syntax you've shown will not actually run a query). You may want to post another question with details about what you want. Post the link here and I'll take a look after I wake up, but someone else may answer before then.

Comment: @Farshad And more probably, for the sake of clearness, you need a `belongsTo` not `hasOne`.

Comment: @patricus can u help me out with this one too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895038/laravel-hasmany-relationship-view-in-blade-laravel-5-6/

Comment: @partricus - EXCELLENT answer... I've been a "dry and dirty" Laravel guy for about a year and expanding my horizons.  This helped me with getting the relationship info passed into the view.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Remove `first()` method call, you don’t need this because you have retrieved the `users` by doing:

`{{ $clients->users->title }}`

Note that if you want to use `first()` call, you should change the query like:

`{{ $client->users()->first()->title }}`

Notice the difference between `users` and `users()` in fetching eloquent relationship.

Also since your relationship is hasOne, you should change `users` to `user` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is there anyway to use latest() or anything else instead of first()? just for changing the first one

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a collection of clients so you need to iterate through the collection.

You are defining a hasOne relationship on your client model called users.  First of all as its a hasOne relationship you should name it appropriately, in this case just user.

You can also define it much cleaner:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

Now your second issue is how you are trying to retrieve this relationship.

Lets say you are passing a collection of clients to your view, something like:

```
public function clients()
{
    $clients = Client::with('user')->get();
    return view('view.view.view', compact('clients');
}
```

In your blade you need to now iterate through your clients to get their user relationship:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $client->user->user_column_name }}
@endforeach
```

Hope that helps.

Just remember try and make your naming as easy to understand as possible, yeah this project might be for your eyes only but just this simple snippet of code becomes obscure for someone who's never seen it to get what's going on.

Comment: thanks man that helped and one more question is it the same for hasmany relations ?

Comment: public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id','product_id');
    }

Comment: $products = Invoice::with('products')->get();
        return view('admin.invoices.show', compact('invoice', $invoice),compact('clients',$clients))->with(compact('products',$products));
    }

Comment: @foreach($products as $product)
                                <td>{{ $product->product->name ?? 'no products' }}</td>
                            @endforeach

Comment: so is it possible to do it like this and then send 2 variables that contain relations to view ?

Comment: When you define your relationship my friend, simply do: return $this->relationshipType(ModelName::class);

Comment: When you send data to the view all you need to do is one compact and the variable name e.g. return view('view', compact('invoices', 'clients', 'products');

Comment: oh thanks i really had problem with that :) thanks really :)

Comment: can u help me out with this question too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895038/laravel-hasmany-relationship-view-in-blade-laravel-5-6/50895055#50895055