# Cannot display related entities in one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a one-to-many relationship in my code that I want to show on my view, but I get a `NULL` error. Below is the model with the defined relationship.

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id', 'product_id');
}
```

This is my controller method:

```
$products = Invoice::with('products')->get();
return view('admin.invoices.show', 
    compact('invoice', $invoice),
    compact('clients', $clients))->with(compact('products', $products));
```

This is my view, but it always displays *no products*:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <td>{{ $product->product->name ?? 'no products' }}</td>
@endforeach
```

When I `dd()` the `$products` array, I get the following:

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "products" => Collection {#321 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Product {#318 ▼
          #fillable: array:5 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:8 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "asd"
```

EDIT

here is my full controller that i get the relation with users with no problem thats a hasOne relation but i cant access the products relation and that s main problem

```
public function show(Invoice $invoice)
{
    $clients = Invoice::with('user')->get();
    $products = Invoice::with('products')->get();
    return view('admin.invoices.show', compact('invoice', $invoice),compact('clients',$clients))->with(compact('products',$products));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included now your controller code. So in fact instead of

```
public function show(Invoice $invoice)
{
    $clients = Invoice::with('user')->get();
    $products = Invoice::with('products')->get();
    return view('admin.invoices.show', compact('invoice', $invoice),compact('clients',$clients))->with(compact('products',$products));
}
```

you can use only:

```
public function show(Invoice $invoice)
{
    return view('admin.invoices.show', compact('invoice', $invoice));
}
```

and in your view to display invoice products you can use:

```
@forelse ($invoice->products as $product) 
  {{ $product->name }}
@empty
   no products
@endforelse
```

Comment: no friend i am trying to print an invoice and that invoice can have 2 products for example ofc i am working on 1 product for now :)

Comment: so i set the relation of invoice with products to hasmany so my invoice can have many products

Comment: @Farshad so this is what I showed in my code, but you probably didn't include the whole controller code for this. Update your question with full controller method code

Comment: @Farshad You can also take a look at my edited answer

Comment: @marchin nabialek my dear friend i think you got me wrong take a look at my edited question thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

replace `{{ $product->product->name ?? 'no products' }}` by:

`{{ $product->name ?? 'no products' }}`

Also edit `@foreach($products as $product)` to `@foreach($products->products->all() as $product)`

Comment: again the same null returns

Comment: Property [product] does not exist on this collection instance :(

Comment: Property [products] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @foreach($products->products as $product)
                                <td>{{ $product->name ?? 'no products' }}</td>
                            @endforeach

Comment: even i added all() and yet again the same output

Comment: try `@foreach($products['products'] as $product)`

Comment: yet agian Undefined index: products :(